# ThreeJS VR : how to position an object in front of one eye

Tags: three.js, camera, position, virtual-reality

I have found a way to always keep an object right in front of the camera in VR: I don't add it to the scene directly but to the camera (which is then added to the scene with its childs). By doing so, if I move my head, the object is always located right in front of me:

```
const object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
scene.add(camera)
camera.add(object)
object.position.set(0,0,-1)
```

Now, instead of having it located right in front of me in stereo view (while looking at it with both eyes in the HMD), I would like to have it located in front of the left lens only.

I understood that even if we deal with a single camera in our scene, ThreeJS is rendering the scene 2 times for each eye through a "left camera" and "right camera" internally (to create the stereo effect in the HMD) so I tried to add an offset to the object in the scene to match the offset of the left camera:

```
object.position.set(-0.057,-0.08,-1)
```

It is kinda working but it is of course not accurate and only based on my judgement and some iterations for adjusting its position.

How could I exactly know the offset that I have to set in order to have it 100% in front of the left lens (vertically and horizontally) ? I tried to dynamically find the position of those internal camera but I could not get it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the onBeforeRender event. this has renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material, group. Then find a way to see which camera is left and which one is right.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).